# Drupal ajax_command_after function

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

Regarding the ajax_command_after() function in Drupal 7

Currently I have it working and outputting some content.
however it wraps the content in an unlabelled DIV (no class, no id ect).

Is there a way to make it add an ID to this DIV so that I can target the DIV later?

The functions documentation says that its final argument is an array of settings but the only thing it says about the settings is...

"$settings: An optional array of settings that will be used for this command only".

It does not say what settings are available or how to use them.

Can the required ID for the wrapper DIV be inserted here
if yes
What would the syntax be?

This is the relevant documentation
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_after/7

I also could not find an example of this in Drupals examples module.

my code is

```
function view_file_page(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $connection = connect();

    $ID = $args[0];
    $row = $args[2];

    $stream = $connection->getContentStream($ID);

    // Create a new AJAX command that replaces the #page text with our own text.
    $ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_after('#' . $row, $stream);
    $ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_remove('#name-and-slogan');

//    $ajax_commands[0]['method'] = 'replaceWith';
//    $sam = $ajax_commands[0]['method'];

    // Return our commands in JSON.
    ajax_deliver(array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $ajax_commands));
}
```

Comment: How did you use the function? (show code please)

Comment: I have managed to ge the desired result by making the following change

$ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_after('#' . $row, '<div id="content_' . $row . '">' .  $stream . '</div>');

note that when i do this i do not get an <DIV> tag wrapped arround my hard coded div that has an ID